# How the compare function calls the array element and what is the order of the calls

Tags: c

I have a problem in `qsort(arr, n, sizeof(int), compare)`
here how the compare calls its parameter. As I known its a void pointer and it calls the address of the array element and then it compares the value. But how it known the order of array element.

I also attached the whole code and function definition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compare(const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main ()
{
    int arr[] = {10, 5, 15, 12, 90, 80};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), i;
    qsort (arr, n, sizeof(int), compare);
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf ("%d ", arr[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. The `compare` function receives pointers to the two values to compare. That's all. BTW your code looks correct to me.

Comment: Beware using a subtraction to return the comparison - it can overflow. It is better to make two specific comparions and then default to equality.

Comment: I first thanks  for your advice    ,,, my question is how function known to which element of array is the first and which is second one . i don't understand order of the input taken by function.            ..  I agree with your explanation for not using subtraction in return.

Comment: It doesn't know the order of the elements - the purpose of the compare function is to tell qsort the order, because only you know the sorting criteria. Consider the situation where you are sorting an array of struct, only you know which field to sort on.

Comment: @AnkitKumar the compare function has 2 parameters, the first one points to the first item, the second one points to the second item. _You_ know that the items are `int`s, therefore you cast these pointer to `int`pointers with `(int*)`. `*(int*)a` is the first item to compare and `*(int*)b is the second item to compare. BTW what do you mean by if "vpis" ? Do you know what a poinbter is ? If not you should read about pointers first.

Comment: @Michael Walz,@Weather Vane: Sorry for being imprecise. Actually I wanted to know how does compare function get the value for void * a and void * b at below line :                                                                                                  int compare(const void * a, const void * b)                                                      as  a and b are  not passed when we call the function compare as shown  below :                                                                                                             qsort (arr, n, sizeof(int), compare);

Comment: @AnkitKumar: You pass the pointer to the `compare` function when you call `qsort`. The `qsort` function takes care of calling the compare function. You should read about _function pointers_.

Comment: @Michael Walz: Thank you. It would be really helpful if you can please share how does qsort take care of this? Or if you can share some link/document for the same..

Comment: @AnkitKumar google _c function pointer_

Comment: @ Michael Walz: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried but I still don't understand how does the value of a and b are passed to compare when we are not passing any parameter to it while calling it in bellow line                                qsort (arr, n, sizeof(int), compare);Please  suggest.

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nitems, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void*)){

    char *ptr1, *ptr2;
    int j, i;

    for (j = 0 ; j < nitems ; j++){
        ptr1 = ((char*) base) + (j * size);
        for( i = 0 ; i < nitems ; i++){
           ptr2 = ((char*) base) + (i * size);
           if( compar(ptr1, ptr2)) {
               ...
           }
       }
    }
    ...
}
```